# Getting NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate this from. But when I try to send a text to a text fields it is getting `NoSuchElementException`. I have tried `webdriverwait` also. But no luck. There is a popup on top of the window. I closed it and also I tried adding `--disable-popup-blocking` argument. But still it is not working. So anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong here? I highly appreciate that. Thank you.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(URL);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#txt_insert2055107")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#txt_insert2055107")).sendKeys("Test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txt_insert2055108")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txt_insert2055108")).sendKeys("Test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnsubmit")).click();

    driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant send text on your input because you need to switch to iframe firts. Please find below working code:

```
https://www.frontrush.com/FR_Web_App/Player/PlayerSubmit.aspx?sid=MTA1NTc=-9M6ha/5BuDo=&ptype=recruit
```

**code:**

```
        driver.get("https://columbiacougars.com/sb_output.aspx?frform=8&path=mbball");
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement firstName=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("txt_insert2055107")));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", firstName);
        action.moveToElement(firstName).sendKeys("Test").perform();
        WebElement lastName=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("txt_insert2055108")));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", lastName);
        lastName.sendKeys("Test");
        action.moveToElement(lastName).sendKeys("Test").perform();
        WebElement clickElement=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("btnsubmit")));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", clickElement);
        driver.close();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But still I am getting this error `ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <iframe src="https://www.frontrush.com/` when I am going to click the `Last Name`. Can you help me to resolve that?

Comment: I have provided code it's working fine for me and we are trying to switch onto the iframe based on index. Copy my code as it's and paste it in your ide , you don't need to click on iframe , we need to switch driver on iframe before dealing with form web elements

Comment: When going to bottom, the bottom blue bar is coming up. Then that error is throwing. `jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");` is not working properly. Do you have any idea?